# SQLite3 joining rows to form a single row

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an android application which queries a database for a bus number, and bus departure time.

The tables are thus -

Table 1: Route - _id, routenumber

Table 2: Routetimedetails - _id, routetime, routeid

My current query is this

> select routenumber, route._id, routetime from route, routetimedata where route._id = 2 and routeid = route._id

and the result shows up like this 
>

> ```
> routenumber | route._id | routetime
> -------------------------------------
> BIAS10      | 2         | 0945
>
> BIAS10      | 2         | 1810
>
> BIAS10      | 2         | 1945
>
> BIAS10      | 2         | 0710
> ```

is there a way in sqlite3 to show the result in a single column like this -

> ```
> BIAS10      | 2         | 0710, 0945, 1810, 1945
> ```

Thanks
Mukul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that the Group_Concat() function does this easily

> select routenumber, route._id, Group_concat(routetime) from route, routetimedata where route._id = 2 and routeid = route._id